# python slicing a string of numbers in to sections based on lengths within the string

Tags: python, slice

I have a string of numbers that I want to read from a file and parse into sub-sections, with lengths of the subsections based on numbers within the string. The first number in the string is the length of the first sub-section. So for example, if I have a string of data as follows:
4, 11, 22, 33, 3, 44, 55, 5, 44, 55, 66, 77

I want to divide up as follows:

first subsection is length 4, so, 4, 11, 22, 33

second subsection is length 3, so 3, 44, 55

third subsection is length 5, so 5, 44, 55, 66, 77

I tried using variables in slice, so that I could increment the start/stop values as I march through the data, but it doesn't take vars. I worked out a way to delete each subsection as I go so that the first value will always be the length of the next subsection, but it seems sort of clunky.

I'd appreciate any suggestions - thx

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like:

```
your_list = [4, 11, 22, 33, 3, 44, 55, 5, 44, 55, 66, 77]
subsec = []
it = iter(your_list)
for n in it:
    subsec.append([n] + map(lambda x: next(it), range(int(n-1))))
```

This way you only loop once over your list.

or

```
for n in it:
    subsec.append([n] + [next(it) for _ in range(int(n-1))])
```

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with more complex logic, I prefer to use regular loops.

In this case I would go with a `while` loop, running until the list is empty, and removing the elements already processed. If the sections are wrong (i.e. the last section goes beyond the size of the string), the assert will tell you.

```
sequence = [4, 11, 22, 33, 3, 44, 55, 5, 44, 55, 66, 77]
sections = []
while sequence:
    section_size = sequence[0]
    assert len(sequence) >= section_size
    sections.append(sequence[:section_size])
    sequence = sequence[section_size:]

print sections
```

This splits the sections and save them in a list called `sections`, with the size as first element, like in your examples.

Edit: added error checking.

Comment: I wouldn't use `list` as a variable.

Comment: +1. I concur btw, this seems like a very bad way to denote partitions in a list. If something is wrong, checking for errors would be at least as complex as partitioning the list to begin with.

Comment: I'm sorry, did you mean my solution is hard to check for errors or *wasserfeder*'s is? Just to be sure I added error checking to mine, it's actually shorter than commenting about it.

Comment: Haha. Yes I see, and I stand corrected. I had in mind something closer to *error correcting*.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd throw this out there. Very similar to both BoppreH's solution, but it avoids the overhead of creating `n` additional lists by iterating over indices:

```
def generateSlices(seq):
    i = 0
    while i < len(seq):
        n = x[i]
        yield x[i:i + n]
        i += n
```

You can check for errors after generating a list of sublists by doing:

```
mySubLists = [[5, 23, 33, 44, 2], [10]]

all(len(x) == x[0] for x in mySubLists)
```

Incidentally, why is your data structured in this strange way? It seems error-prone.

Comment: the data looks this way because that's how USB descriptor data is returned to the host. thanks to all for the help - really appreciate it! @wasserfeder